# Creating a PyInstaller bundle with a Python application that has multiple entry-points

Tags: pyinstaller

I am trying to wrap some software I wrote into a standalone installer. First, I use PyInstaller to create a stand-alone folder that can be redistributed to end-users. Then, I use NSIS to create a nice installer that unpacks the folder created by PyInstaller and then creates a set of shortcuts in the start menu to easily launch the program.

For more simple programs where there's a single entry-point, e.g., under `[project.scripts]` in `pyproject.toml`, I would have the following:

```
   run-program = "my_program.main:main"
```

For this, I simply point PyInstaller to a script named `run-program.py` with the following contents:

```
   from my_program import main
   main()
```

However, I now have an application with many entry-points, e.g.:

```
   run-experiment-1 = "my_program.main:main_1"
   run-experiment-2 = "my_program.main:main_2"
   run-experiment-3 = "my_program.main:main_3"
   ...
   run-experiment-N = "my_program.main:main_N"
```

This means creating a script for each of these `run-experiment` entry-points and then passing them all to PyInstaller. While this works, it seems horribly inefficient. First, it takes a *long* time for PyInstaller to check all the dependencies. Second, the EXE files generated seem to be surprisingly large.

If I create a separate module for each of my entry-points, e.g.:

```
   run-experiment-1 = "my_program.main.main_1"
   run-experiment-2 = "my_program.main.main_2"
   run-experiment-3 = "my_program.main.main_3"
   ...
   run-experiment-N = "my_program.main.main_N"
```

and then add an `if __name__ == __main__` to execute the `main()` function in each of these modules, then I could easily set up the shortcuts in the start menu so they can invoke Python modules, e.g., the shortcut would point to python.exe -m my_program.main.main_1`. However, is there a way to bundle a "pure" or single Python executable via PyInstaller rather than a separate *.exe for each entry-point?